# uniformly converge of a serie with given conditons

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, continuity, uniform-convergence

i have this question about series.
So i came along a question that started with :
$(f_{n})_{n}$:[-1,1]->$R^{+}$ is a row of continuous functions. The serie $\sum{f_{k}(x)}$ from k=0 to $\inf$ will converges and thefunction f:[-1,1]->$R^{+}$:x->$\sum(f_{k}(x))$ is continuous.

Now i wanted to prove that $\sum f_{k}$ uniformly converges.

I wanted to use the M-test from weierstrass. Therefore i only needed to prove that |$f_{k}(x)|$<= $f_{k}(x)$. For this i wanted to use that f is continous but i'm stuck and not sure if we can even say that it uniformly converge.

Comment: That is not the M test. Take a look again at the [Weierstrass M-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tha follows from [Dini's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dini%27s_theorem): since each $f_n$ take only non-negative values, the sequence $\left(\sum_{n=1}^Nf_n(x)\right)_{N\in\Bbb N}$ is monotonic increasing for each $x\in[-1,1]$. So, since each $\sum_{n=1}^Nf_n$ is continuous and since $f$ is continuous, the convergence is uniform.

Comment: i'm really not seeing it, can you maybe write a more specific prove?

Comment: I provided a complete proof. Which more details do you need?

Comment: if i'm using Dini's theorem, which i only saw in metric spaces, i don't have all the conditons to say that the serie converges uniformly

Comment: The sequence $\left(\sum_{n=1}^Nf_n(x)\right)_{N\in\Bbb N}$ is monotonic increasing sequence of continuous functions which converges pointwise to a continuous function. Which condition is missing?

Comment: no you're right thank you :)